# How to turn off FORTIFY_SOURCE patch using format string bug

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, format-string, fortify-source

This question is relative to : A Eulogy for Format Strings from phrack (http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=67&id=9)

```
//File: test.c
//gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2
int main(){
  char buf[256];
  fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
  printf(buf);
}
```

I don't understand in their article how providing a fmt string like %1$*269168516$ it can toggle off _IO_FLAGS2_FORTIFY bit in the `stdout` FILE structure ?

Is it because when we overflow the integer offset, args_type[offset] can point anywhere in memory, and specifically on stdout->_flags2 to set it to 0 ?

If so, how can we know that we managed to toggle it off ? because when I try with this code I can't get a segfault like specified in the article. (compiling option: gcc -m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -ggdb -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -o prog test.c)

```
(gdb) disas vprintf
Dump of assembler code for function vprintf:
   0xf7e9ed90 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0xf7e9ed91 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0xf7e9ed93 <+3>: push   %ebx
   0xf7e9ed94 <+4>: sub    $0xc,%esp
   0xf7e9ed97 <+7>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0xf7e9ed9a <+10>:    call   0xf7f6ac66
   0xf7e9ed9f <+15>:    add    $0x11b255,%ebx
   0xf7e9eda5 <+21>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0xf7e9eda9 <+25>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0xf7e9edac <+28>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0xf7e9edb0 <+32>:    mov    -0x7c(%ebx),%eax
   0xf7e9edb6 <+38>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0xf7e9edb8 <+40>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0xf7e9edbb <+43>:    call   0xf7e99a60 <vfprintf>
   0xf7e9edc0 <+48>:    add    $0xc,%esp
   0xf7e9edc3 <+51>:    pop    %ebx
   0xf7e9edc4 <+52>:    pop    %ebp
   0xf7e9edc5 <+53>:    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because when we overflow the integer offset, args_type[offset]
>   can point anywhere in memory, and specifically on stdout->_flags2 to
>   set it to 0 ?

Yes.

> If so, how can we know that we managed to toggle it off ?

You test it by using `%n` in your format string. If it doesn't error out then you have succeeded.

> I can't get a segfault like specified in the article

If you mean entering `%n` doesn't give you:

```
*** %n in writable segment detected ***
Aborted
```

Then you don't have the `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` properly enabled to start with.

Comment: Ok it works. But I don't get why they say "We will pick some ridiculous desination, like %1$*269168516$. If it
doesn't crash, keep incrementing that by about 20000." Why do they want it to crash ? And how can we find the right width parameter because I have tried numbers above the one I used here and a little bit below and everytime I don't get the error message ? Is it because once we go above a certain MAXIMUM every value above will point to stdout->_flags2 ? (%1$*269168515$x, %1$*26916851888$x, etc... are valid)

Comment: The crash is provoked so that the instruction which does the write can be easily located. It's not yet overwriting the flag, so the only important thing is to find an invalid address. The correct value will be then calculated knowing the value in `ecx` at the time of the crash.

Comment: you mean we want to locate : stdout->_flags2 |= _IO_FLAGS2_FORTIFY; ? I don't get how I can get the crash, do I have to bruteforce until I get it crashes ?

Comment: No, it locates the `args_type[specs[cnt].width_arg] = PA_INT;`. You could also just disassemble `vfprintf` in gdb and try to find the line.